# Force coverage increase in gitlab PRs

Tags: ember.js, gitlab, code-coverage, gitlab-ci

In an effort to increase test coverage by requiring unit tests for every pull request on my EmberJS project hosted on gitlab, I want pipelines to **fail if the coverage doesn't increase**.

I can get the coverage output using [istanbul](https://github.com/kategengler/ember-cli-code-coverage) and get the coverage badge displaying correctly using the following regex:

[image: Gitlab CI screenshot]

And using this `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: sergiolepore/ember-cli

before_script:
  - yarn --ignore-engines
  - bower --allow-root install

"Ember Unit Tests":
  script:
    - COVERAGE=true npm test -- --filter=Unit
    - grep -o '"pct":\d*\.\d*' coverage/coverage-summary.json | head -1
```

How can I get the next pipeline to fail if the coverage is decreased in a PR?

Comment: you just need to exit with a non-zero exit code and the pipeline will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of digging through https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/, here's the solution I found:

#### 1. Generate code coverage while executing tests

That pipeline will store the coverage percentage under `coverage/.current` between jobs using [artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts)

```
"Ember Unit Tests":
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - coverage/.current
  script:
    - COVERAGE=true yarn test --filter=Unit
  after_script:
    - grep -o <regex> coverage.json >> coverage/.current
```

#### 2. Compare code coverage with stored "max" coverage (0 by default)

If the coverage decreased, simply return a non-zero exit code (Thank you Lux!)

```
"Increase Coverage":
  before_script:
    - MAX=`if [ -f coverage/.max ] ; then cat coverage/.max ; else echo 00.00 ; fi`
    - CURRENT=`cat coverage/.current`
  script: if [[ $CURRENT < $MAX ]] ; then exit 1 ; fi
```

#### 3. Update the "max" coverage when merging pull requests

```
"Update Max Coverage":
  except:
    - pushes
  before_script:
    - NEW_MAX=`cat coverage/.current`
  script: echo $NEW_MAX > coverage/.max
```

Run those three pipelines in succession using [stages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages) and don't forget to cache the "max" coverage between pipelines:

```
cache:
  paths:
    - coverage/.max
```